# Migrating B2C OWIN service from "login.microsoft.com" to "b2clogin.com"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

So I've been migrating an older app service and Xamarin mobile application away from the old versions of MSAL to the latest as well as re-directing my app from 'login.microsoft.com' to the new(er) 'b2clogin.com' issuer URIs. I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multiple-token-endpoints) to migrate to the new issuer URI while still remaining backwards compatible with applications currently out in the field.

However, I'm running this service as an Azure App Service and in the 'Authentication / Authorization' section of my service I have my Active Directory configured with the correct B2C Application 'Client ID' and there's another text box for 'Issuer URL'. I can't seem to get away with not having a URI in that text box whether it be:

```
https://[id].b2clogin.com/[app id]/B2C_1_SignInUp/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

or

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app id]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_SignIn
```

Now this does authenticate just fine as long as I have one issuer or the other issuer but in my code I have:

```
TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
            ValidAudience = ClientId,
            AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy,
            ValidIssuers = new List<string> {
                    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app id]/oauth2/v2.0/",
                    "https://[id].b2clogin.com/[app id]/oauth2/v2.0/"
                }
        };
```

Which I believe should mean that both issuers should be valid (backwards compatible. I've put in a little bit of debug code to verify that this code is being executed at startup. It *almost* seems like the Azure service is overriding the multiple issuer code but I'm not sure?

Does this documentation work in the Azure App service or is there something more you have to do to configure it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Authentication / Authorization aka Easy Auth runs before your app code.
So it will only accept one issuer.

I would suggest doing authentication only in your code, and turning off Easy Auth as it cannot fulfill your requirements here.

Comment: Thanks for the response @juunas, do you know of an example project that shows how to do this without Easy Auth on? Thanks!